# Images are not displayed for Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, freemarker, html-rendering

Firstly, sorry for my bad English. And my question: 
I try display report preview on html page. For it, set parameters:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outFilePath);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, "/preview/image?image=");
exporter.exportReport();
```

As can be seen, we export report into html file in the specified directory. In web, I added the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/preview/image</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For displaying html, we have ftl controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/events/preview", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public void reportPreviewEvents(String requestInJson,
                                @RequestParam("pageSize") Integer pageSize,
                                @RequestParam("pageNo") Integer pageNo,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                HttpServletRequest request,
                                Model model) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> toModel = auditHandler.handleExportEvents(requestInJson, JasperExporter.Type.HTML, pageSize, pageNo, request);
        model.addAllAttributes(toModel);
        String filePath = (String) toModel.get("filePath");
        reportContent = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(filePath), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(reportContent);
```

But when I open it (ip:port/context/report/events/preview/), I can't see images in html.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In addition: that I found http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531045/image-not-displayed-html-view. Last comment. I used 5.0.4 version

Comment: Error was found. It need context for images uri, like: exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/preview/image?image=");

Comment: Simply can get related path from request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you can generate a HTML report and point to your image servlet for the newer JasperReports libraries (I am using 6.1.0), as a lot of the old functions are deprecated:

```
StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();        
HtmlExporter exporterHTML = new HtmlExporter();
SimpleExporterInput exporterInput = new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint);
exporterHTML.setExporterInput(exporterInput);

SimpleHtmlExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(sbuffer);
//pointing to the image servlet
HtmlResourceHandler imageHandler = new WebHtmlResourceHandler( request.getContextPath() + "/servlets/image?" + ImageServlet.IMAGE_NAME_REQUEST_PARAMETER
        + "={0}" + "&uuid=" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
exporterOutput.setImageHandler(imageHandler);

//setting some sonfigs for the report
SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration htmlConfig = new SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration();
SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration htmlReportConfiguration = new SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration();
htmlConfig.setHtmlFooter("");
htmlConfig.setHtmlHeader("");
htmlConfig.setBetweenPagesHtml("");
htmlReportConfiguration.setPageIndex(pageIndex);

exporterHTML.setConfiguration(htmlConfig);
exporterHTML.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);
exporterHTML.setConfiguration(htmlReportConfiguration);

exporterHTML.exportReport();
```

Hope someone finds it helpful.